# My input gets lost somewhere along the way(printing 0s)

Tags: c#, arrays, output

Trying to sort a list of data that contains the following:

The txt. file currently looks like this but will be extended to include more, about 100 or so. 900 is just used as an upper limit.

21,f, s, 14

41,f, m, 22

12, m, s, 12

11, f, s, 8

29, m, m, 4

6, m, s, 12

9, f, s, 2

30, f, s, 1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    const int SIZE = 900;
    const int SIZEDISTRICT = 22;
    const int RANGE = 5;
    static void Main()
    {   
        //These arrays will hold the split data from a text file.
        int[] districtDataD = new int[900];
        string[] districtDataG = new string[900];
        string[] districtDataM = new string[900];
        int[] districtDataA = new int[900];

        //countDistrict will hold how many hypothetical people in each hypothetical district and 
        //ages will hold how many hypothetical people between certain hypothetical ages.
        int[] countDistrict = new int[SIZEDISTRICT];
        int[] ages = new int[RANGE] { 0, 18, 30, 45, 65};


        //Modules
        ReadFile(districtDataD, districtDataG, districtDataM,districtDataA);
        CountPopulation(districtDataD, countDistrict);
        AgeRanges(districtDataA, ages);
        DisplayData(countDistrict, districtDataA, ages);
    }//End Main


    //This module splits and inserts the data into the four first arrays
    static void ReadFile(int[] districtDataD, string[] districtDataG, string[] districtDataM, int[] districtDataA)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("census.txt");
        int i = 0;

        while (i < SIZE  && i < 0)
        {
            foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("census.txt"))
            {
                string[] parts = line.Split(',');

                districtDataD[i] = int.Parse(parts[0]);
                districtDataG[i] = parts[1];
                districtDataM[i] = parts[2];
                districtDataA[i] = int.Parse(parts[3]);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    //This module counts how many hypothetical people are in each fictional district
   static void CountPopulation(int[] districtDataD, int[] countDistrict)
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < districtDataD.Length; i++)
        {
            if (districtDataD[i] > 0 && districtDataD[i] < districtDataD.Length)
            {
                districtDataD[countDistrict[i]]
                    ++;
            }
        }
    }


    //This module sorts the ages into 0-18, 19-30, 31-45, 46-65, and 65 and up
     private static void AgeRanges(int[] districtDataA, int[] ages)
     {
         int idx = 0;
         for (idx = 0; idx < districtDataA.Length && ages[idx] > districtDataA[idx]; idx++)
         {

             ages[idx] = districtDataA[idx];
         }
     }


    //This module displays the data
     static void DisplayData(int[] countDistrict, int[] districtDataA, int[] ages)
    {
        int index = 0;
        for (index = 0; index < countDistrict.Length; index++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" District {0}: {1}", index + 1, countDistrict[index]);
        }

        int x = 0;
        for (x = 0; x < ages.Length; x++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ages over {0} : {1}", ages[x], districtDataA[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

The current output looks like this:

[image: A bunch of zeroes]

Where is my data getting lost?

Comment: You tried to debug it?

Comment: Is this line correct `while (i < SIZE  && i < 0)` in your `ReadFile` method?

Comment: Quickly plugging this into Visual Studio and I can see @Barry above, is indeed correct.

Comment: I changed it to (i < SIZE  && i > 0) and it's the the same.  Thanks for catching that though.

Comment: @Barry problem is in this line. This never returns true. So loop never executes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line.

```
while (i < SIZE && i < 0)
```

This loop never executes. Replace it with this.

```
while (i < SIZE && i <= 0)
{
    foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("census.txt"))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
        {
            string[] parts = line.Split(',');

            districtDataD[i] = int.Parse(parts[0]);
            districtDataG[i] = parts[1];
            districtDataM[i] = parts[2];
            districtDataA[i] = int.Parse(parts[3]);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are good in debugging then you will come to know what is problem. It will crash when loop will be executed second time. Because line will be empty string.

Comment: I'm new at this.  I'm not sure if it's a logic error that can be caught in deskchecking or something C# related.

Comment: @Sabotenderizer, one problem at a time. Make a new topic for a different problem. Has his answer worked? If so, accept it, move on, research your next problem and let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: Only works for ages, and even so, prints out the ages themselves not the amount of times each age appears.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ReadFile` is wrong. Try something like this instead.

```
static void ReadFile(int[] districtDataD, string[] districtDataG, string[] districtDataM, int[] districtDataA)
{
   // Read in the file contents
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("census.txt");
    int i =0;
    //iterate through each line
    foreach(var line in lines)
    {
      //split the line by a comma
      string[] parts = line.Split(',');

            districtDataD[i] = int.Parse(parts[0]);
            districtDataG[i] = parts[1];
            districtDataM[i] = parts[2];
            districtDataA[i] = int.Parse(parts[3]);
            i++;
    }

}
```

You are currently reading in the file and assigning it to `lines` then reading the file in again and assigning the value to `line`.  If you use `foreach` you can easily loop through each line without having to keep track of which line you are on.