# Grouping together data from arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

Without using anything like List, ArraySort, Classes, Structs, Objects, LINQ etc how would I group together say a list of ages I took from a survey, each element in the array representing one person's age.

Then have a method that counts how many people are in each age, then groups those people into 5 age groups, 0-18, 18-30, 31-45, 46-64, and 65 and older.  Say like there are are 8 people who are age 18-30 something like that.

I thought I had this down by combining two ways of doing it, first by incrementing the counting array by the array with the data, and the other to group the data with a while loop but it just seems to display the ages themselves.

Comment: I guess this is an interview question or something given the ridiculous constraints? (EDIT: hmmm C# without objects...)

Comment: I'm sorry, but how is "Classes, Structs, or Objects" 'fancy'?

Comment: No it's part of a class assignment.  One I've been working on for days with little progress.

Comment: @Sabotenderizer; perhaps you should show what you've got so far rather than expect the whole solution to be posted for you.

Comment: This is the 3rd question I see about this subject today. We might as well complete the entire assignment for you, right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876082/my-input-gets-lost-somewhere-along-the-wayprinting-0s

Comment: Oh... I really don't get what does a class assignment like this prove.

Comment: @Dampe when it comes to _learning_ programming, it's important to learn the basics of how a computer processes, basics of looping, and just plain old training your brain to think logically and methodically. What's the point of using LINQ or Lists if you can't actually understand what goes on behind the scenes?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I think most of my trouble is trying to do this without classes or structs, even though that is optional maybe I should do that instead.  I have almost no way of understanding how to do this with classes instead of arrays, or can it be both classes an arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Initializing

```
int[] input = new int[] { 5, 10, 20, 35, 50, 68 };
int[,] ageGroups = new int[5, input.Length];
int[] ageCounters = new int[5];
```

Grouping

```
foreach(int age in input)
{
    if(age >= 0 && age < 18)
    {
        ageGroups[0, ageCounters[0]] = age;
        ageCounters[0]++;
    }
    else if(age >= 18 && age <= 30)
    {
        ageGroups[1, ageCounters[1]] = age;
        ageCounters[1]++;
    }
    else if(age >= 31 && age <= 45)
    {
        ageGroups[2, ageCounters[2]] = age;
        ageCounters[2]++;
    }
    else if(age >= 46 && age <= 64)
    {
        ageGroups[3, ageCounters[3]] = age;
        ageCounters[3]++;
    }
    else if(age >= 65)
    {
        ageGroups[4, ageCounters[4]] = age;
        ageCounters[4]++;
    }
}
```

Displaying

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < ageCounters[i]; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(ageGroups[i, j] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: How do I adapt this into a loop? tried to but got a but of 14s for some reason.  Also I can't have more than one index variable in an indexer.